# Need to compare 2 php files and fix the old one

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a big problem and I need help please.

After wordpress updating from 3.5.2 to 3.6+ I have a problem with a specific function of a php file.

This file is responsible for any extra user data (eg city, country, etc.) which are stored in wp_usermeta table. 
My knowledge in php is minimal. I managed and found a newer file but has too many differences and I can not figure out which are the data I need.

The old one works fine for everything else except this piece of code:

```
    $_POST['form']['ID']        = $userdata->ID;
    $_POST['form']['jabber']    = $_POST['address']['country']."**";
    $_POST['form']['jabber']    .= $_POST['address']['state']."**";
    $_POST['form']['jabber']    .= $_POST['address']['address']."**";
    $_POST['form']['jabber']    .= $_POST['address']['city']."**";
    $_POST['form']['jabber']    .= $_POST['address']['zip']."**";
    $_POST['form']['jabber']    .= $_POST['address']['phone'];
```

This piece of code if operated, would create inside wp_usermeta table, a meta_key **"jabber"** & a meta_value **"country*state*address*city*zip*phone"**

This file is also responsible for other things like User Name, Surname, email, orders etc. Everything works fine except the previous code.

I have also try to manually add the records in database and my sript read the user data without problems, the only problem is to save the data.

**This is the old php file with the problem:**
[OldPhp](http://pastebin.com/t4wME55n)

**This is the new one I found but it has many changes:**
[NewPhp](http://pastebin.com/sTg0W2Gu)

Please help me, Nicolas

Comment: Is this a plugin or a core file?

Comment: Just realised it's a plugin (opened link). Are you sure it is those lines of code that's causing it? Steps to debug would be- check the $_POST data and then if that checks out, have a look at the $userdata variable and make sure it's not using a deprecated function

Comment: thank you I will do my best. thanks